# Derive $\sin(\alpha - \beta)$

Tags: trigonometry

Here's me trying to do that. 
[image: www.4gp.tw/b025/1385526053355.jpg]
 After $\frac{BP}{AC} = \frac{BP}{BC}  \frac{BC}{AC} = \cos(\alpha - \beta)\tan(\beta)$, I didn't know what to do next. Theoretically, it should become $\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$ and be something like $\frac{AQ}{AB}  \frac{BC}{AB}$, but I don't know how to get it there.

Thanks.

Comment: @Kat The 10 minutes it will cost you to get the hang of latex is absolutely worth it.

Comment: @DavidH I did the fractions :)

Comment: are you supposed to derive this from scratch, or can you start with a knowledge of cos(a + b)?

Comment: @BettyMock I think I can start with a knowledge of cos(a + b)

Comment: @Kat -- then substitute (-b) for b in your formula for cos(a+b).  John Perry's answer is the best way if you are starting from scratch, but you may not know those formulas.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use Euler's formula,
$e^{i \theta}=\cos \theta+i\sin\theta.$

With this famous formula,

$$e^{i(\alpha-\beta)}=\cos({\alpha-\beta})+i\sin({\alpha-\beta}).$$

Since by law of exponents $e^{i(\alpha-\beta)}=e^{i\alpha}e^{-i\beta}$, we can also write that

$$
\begin{align*}
e^{i(\alpha-\beta)}&=e^{i\alpha}e^{-i\beta} \\
&=(\cos \alpha+i\sin \alpha)(\cos \beta - i \sin \beta) \\
&=\cos \alpha \cos \beta + \sin \alpha \sin \beta + i(\sin \alpha \cos \beta - \sin \beta \cos \alpha).
\end{align*}
$$

As a result,

$$\cos({\alpha-\beta})+i\sin({\alpha-\beta})=\cos \alpha \cos \beta + \sin \alpha \sin \beta + i(\sin \alpha \cos \beta - \sin \beta \cos \alpha).$$

When two complex numbers are equal, the real parts equal real parts, and the imaginary parts equal imaginary parts. Therefore we can conclude, by comparing imaginary parts of the last equation, that
$$\sin({\alpha-\beta})=\sin \alpha \cos \beta - \sin \beta \cos \alpha.$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

From the diagram

\begin{align}
AD&=AB\cos(BAD)=AB\cos(a)=\sin(b)\cos(a)\\
DE&=BC=OB\sin(a)=\cos(b)\sin(a)
\end{align}

thus

$$
\sin(a+b)=AE=DE+AD=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b).
$$

Replacing $b$ with $-b$ and using $\cos(-b)=\cos(b)$ while $\sin(-b)=-\sin(b)$, you get
$$
\sin(a-b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)-\cos(a)\sin(b).
$$

PS The argument is common, but I want to give [credit](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~leili/teaching/math222s11/problems/quizzes/trig.pdf) where it is due, especially for the diagram.

Comment: Is there no way to prove it without negating b?

Comment: You can use a negative $b$, the diagram will just need to change a bit.